# Extract attribute value depending on two others

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<response>
    <result-code fatal="false">0</result-code>
    <lgt from="100" lgt="5.37828" to="644"/>
    <lgt from="100" lgt="354.634640124" to="756"/>
</response>
```

How to find and parse *lgt* attribute value depending on *from* and *to* attribute's value using javascript?

Comment: please explain the question a little more ... what do you expect as a result?

Comment: @jaromanda-x,  XML can contain much more records than in the example. I need to find and parse lgt attribute depending on two others: from and to attributes value. These values must be set as parameters.

Comment: `I need to find andparse lgt attribute depending on two others: from and to attributes value` - you already said that - I was hoping you could explain, given the sample input you have in the question, **what the result should actually BE**

Comment: As a result I need a function:
function parseLGT(from, to) { }

For example: parseLGT(100, 644) should return string "5.37828"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, parse the xml string into an xmlDoc (assuming you aren't using xmlHttpRequest responseXML - skip the conversion in that case)

```
var str = '<response><result-code fatal="false">0</result-code><lgt from="100" lgt="5.37828" to="644"/><lgt from="100" lgt="354.634640124" to="756"/></response>';

var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

at least in firefox/chrome you can use the following -

```
function parseLGT(from, to) {
    var x = xmlDoc.querySelector('lgt[from="' + from + '"][to="' + to + '"]');
    return x && x.getAttribute('lgt')
};
console.log(parseLGT(100,644));
```

IE/Edge - I haven't tested

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse like this:

```
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString('<response><result-code fatal="false">0</result-code><lgt from="100" lgt="5.37828" to="644"/><lgt from="100" lgt="354.634640124" to="756"/></response>', "text/xml");

  // your condition goes here from/to

  if (parseInt(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lgt")[0].getAttribute('to')) < 700) {
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lgt")[0].getAttribute('lgt');
  }
```